# tweepy - get remaining Twitter api rate limit while using cursor

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

Is it possible to get value of HTTP response header from Twitter while using tweepy and Cursors?

I want to know the current API remaining rate limit for my app which should be returned in the header as stated in Twitter API [docs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/rate-limiting.html)(*x-rate-limit-remaining: the number of requests left for the 15 minute window*)

Example code below:

```
import tweepy as tw

for status in tw.Cursor(api.user_timeline, screen_name='@somethingsomething', tweet_mode="extended").items():
    #do something
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

Is doing non-Tweepy request and read the headers the only way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found solution on my own, so basically if you enable debug in Tweepy:

```
import tweepy as tw

tw.debug(True)
```

you'll get it in the logs, for ex.

*header: x-rate-limit-remaining: 138*